# Grabbing single plots from multi-plot output in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm attempting to grab one plot from a multiple plot output. For example

```
library(mboost); 
mod=gamboost(Ozone~.,data=airquality[complete.cases(airquality),]); 
plot(mod)
```

The above creates a plot for each variable's "partial effect". The same could be said for the residual plots created when plotting a linear model (`lm`). I've attempted to save the output in a list akin to how `ggplot`s can be saved and have spent a few hours searching how to extract just one plot but have failed. Any advice?

As for the context of the question, I'm trying to put the plots into a shiny app and have a variable number of plots show up as output.

Session info is as follows:
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-redhat-linux-gnu (32-bit)

Comment: Thanks gung. Sorry about that. I frequent both sites so when I troubleshoot they are one in the same in my mind.

Answer (score 6):

Many functions that produce multiple plots also have an argument to select a subset of the plots.  In the case of `plot.lm` it is the `which` argument.  So saying `plot(fit, which=1)` will only produce one plot.

You can check the mboost documentation to see if there is a similar argument for that plotting function.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, @greg-snow gave a proper solution. I will elaborate this a bit.

In `mboost` you can use

```
plot(mod, which = "Day")
```

to plot the effect of `Day` only. As we use regular expressions you can even do much more using the argument `which`. In a model with linear and smooth effects you can for example extract all smooth effects for plotting:

```
airquality$Month <- as.factor(airquality$Month)
mod <- mod <- gamboost(Ozone ~ bbs(Solar.R) + bbs(Wind) + bbs(Temp) + bols(Month) + bbs(Day), data=airquality[complete.cases(airquality),])

## now plot bbs effects, i.e., smooth effects:
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(mod, which = "bbs")

## or the linear effect only
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
plot(mod, which = "bols")
```

You can use any portion of the name (see e.g. `names(coef(mod))`)to define the effect to be plotted. You can also use integer values to define `which` effect to plot:

```
plot(mod, which = 1:2)
```

Note that this can be also used to certain extract coefficients. E.g.

```
coef(mod, which = 1)
coef(mod, which = "Solar")
coef(mod, which = "bbs(Solar.R)")
```

are all the same. For more on how to specify `which`, both in `coef` and `plot` please see our [tutorial paper](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mboost/vignettes/mboost_tutorial.pdf) (Hofner et al. (2014), Model-based Boosting in R - A Hands-on Tutorial Using the R Package mboost. Computational Statistics, 29:3-35. DOI 10.1007/s00180-012-0382-5).

We acknowledge that this currently isn't documented in `mboost` but it is on our todo list (see [github issue 14](https://github.com/hofnerb/mboost/issues/14)).

Answer (score 1):

*(I'm not familiar with GAMboost.)*

Looking at the documentation for [?plot.GAMBoost](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/GAMBoost/html/plot.GAMBoost.html), I see there is an argument called `select`.  I gather you would set this argument to the variable you are interested in, and then you would get just the single plot you want.  This is analogous the the `which` argument in `plot.lm` that @GregSnow notes.

Comment: Hi Greg & gung - thanks for the reply. I feel like an idiot - I knew of the "which" argument but it wasn't clicking in how to use it as a vector until I read it from someone else. I'm going to do the following: 'plot(mod,which=names(dataSet)[i])' where 'i' can change. That said, can one of you explain the reason why the plots are different when done individually instead of all together? Using the example above: 'par(mfrow=c(2,3)); plot(mod); plot(mod,which="Day")' Day seems to have two different plots...

Comment: I don't know why they're different, @JeP, I'm not really familiar with GAMBoost. Regarding your solution in the comment, note that `plot` will call different methods depending on the class of the object `mod`. Ie, if your mod is lm, then it calls `plot.lm`, but if it's gamboost, it will call `plot.GAMBoost`. The latter uses the `select` argument, not `which`.

Comment: @JeP: The issue that plots are different if they are done individually or all together should be resolved. We used to have a single y-axis scale common to all plots if multiple effects were plotted together. Now, each figure gets its own y-scale in any case. To have the same y-axis for all plots, one now needs to specify `ylim = ...`.

Comment: Please note that `GAMBoost` is a completely different package then `mboost`.